# How to return vertices of rectangle?

Tags: graphics

Given a Rectangle such as `Rectangle[{0,0}, {1,1}]` how can I return the vertices?

solution should look like so:

```
In[1]:= vertices[Rectangle[{0,0}, {1,1}]]
Out[1]= {{0,0},{0,1},{1,1},{1,0}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MeshCoordinates @ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}}
> ```

This gives the coordinates in correct order:

```
Row[Graphics[Polygon @ # @ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
    ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16]] & /@ 
 {MeshCoordinates, PolygonCoordinates}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. May I ask why this correct order is not implemented for `Polygon`s? Or equivalently, where is this polygon ordering used?

Comment: @Syed, I learned about `PolygonCoordinates` from your post :) Re "wrong" ordering of rectangle coords, it might simply be an oversight.

Answer (score 5):

```
r1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];


PolygonCoordinates[r1]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

or

```
MeshPrimitives[r1, 0] // Map[Apply[Sequence]]
```

> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}}

Comment: `Map[Apply[Sequence]]` is equivalent to `Sequence@@@`, so `Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[r1, 0]` is perhaps more readable.

Comment: Thinking from the inside-out as opposed to outside-in. Thanks @MarcoB. It is indeed more readable.